# Hyperparameter optimization on already good values

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, hyperparameter

Which methods are useful and reliable for hyperparameter optimization when the search space is big, the objective function is noisy (some kind of black-box), non-convex, and the model already has very good values (so it's quite hard to optimize)?

Comment: Perhaps a Bayesian optimization approach, where the first few configurations you test are small random perturbations of your current hyperparameters?

Comment: Okay. I was also thinking about SPSA or CLOP, although I don't know them very well. What about them, or random search over a small perturbation of the parameters with small upper and lower bounds?

Comment: I'm not familiar with them, but from Googling it seems like they may be reasonable. You could do worse than random search, but I think a model-based method is nice in this case. If your hyperparameters can be substantially improved upon, a model will advise you on where to search next in a way that random search cannot.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have good values, then you probably want to focus on small improvements instead of going through the entire search space. This makes methods such as Bayesian optimization less desirable. As you mentioned, Confident Local Optimization is one such method, though from a brief glance at it, it seems to be context-dependent. Some other localized search algorithms also include SPSA as you mentioned, as well as simulated annealing. These last two can be applied to more general situations and are quite easy to implement in comparison to many others.

It's worth pointing out that [CLOP: Confident Local Optimization for Noisy Black-Box Parameter Tuning](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-31866-5_13) suggests SPSA to be quite closely competitive to it.

I would not recommend using a global optimization algorithm, such as random search, near your initial point. These algorithms simply aren't built for optimizing near a point, as they often rely on tactics such as exploring the search space. On a localized scale, you can take advantage of the fact that the objective is relatively smooth, meaning minimized exploration and focused refinement in directions you know are likely going to offer good results. Even if you wish to have more exploration, there are methods such as simulated annealing which allow such behaviors.